# "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error with chosen Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So i have used the Chosen Jquery and its working fine.But when i click on submit button which data from Chosen dropdonw and do some calculation and then i am redirection a page. But page redirect dosnt happen at all, its keep coming on the same page. When i check the firebug for an jquery error i see this two error on firebug.

```
    ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...xt="No results match",AbstractChosen}(),a=jQuery,a.fn.extend({chosen:function(b)...


chosen.....min.js (line 2, col 10246)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


$ = jQuery;


chosen.jquery.js (line 523, col 2)
```

I saw my jquery initialization and its above Chosen Jquery plugin,Set up is like this

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>*@

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/chosen.css")" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

i tried adding 1.11.0 also but nothing happen. I thing its really simple issue but i am missing something here.

Please suggest what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: is jquery loaded? as in do you see a 404 error or no

Comment: @kennypu Nope, Dont see any 404 Error. Drop down works and i have a datepicker also on the page which works fine. I found this error when i submit the page and after couple of operation i am redirection the page, but it was not redirecting(didnt got 404 error for that page also).  But in firebug i see these two error message.

Comment: "I submit the page", so does it leave that page and go to another page? make sure the next page it goes on has jquery as well, as whatever page it errors on, it's saying that jquery is not available.

Comment: Yes from my view , it's going to controller and then I run a stored procedure which works fine and if that successfully educated I redirect the page which doesn't work and stay in the same page/view. But when u see fire bug it's gives this error

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to write this in your main.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```